# How to compile my styles in _module.less inside the Amasty_CheckoutCore on the Child Theme in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, css, onepage-checkout, less, less-compilation

I am trying to change the styles in amasty checkout page using the _module.less file and previously I used the _module.less inside the web/css/source in the Child theme to change my theme styles now I need to update the particular module styles using .less file so can anyone help to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your need by create the _module.less file in the following path:

app/design/YourThemeVendor/YourTheme/Amasty_CheckoutCore/web/css/source/_module.less